# Obtener resultado de PHP en callback JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sweetalert2

Tengo un archivo scripts.js así:

```
// ENVIO FORMULARIO POR AJAX
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#form-firma').submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {

                let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                let url_unica = jsonResponse.url_unica;
                                
                console.log("este es el response: " + response + " fin response");

                //SweetAlert
                Swal.fire({
                    html: "<p>Esta es la url_unica: <br> " + url_unica + "</p>",
                    icon: 'success',
                    toast: false,
                    position: 'center',
                    showConfirmButton: true
                })

            }
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

Y el archivo ajax.php es algo así:

```
$url_unica = "https://example.com/valida.php?id_documento=" . $nombre_documento . "&public_key=" . $publicKeyEncoded;

//Lo anterior imprime:
//https://example.com/valida.php?id_documento=2&public_key=random

//Enviar valores al front por medio del callback en script.js
echo json_encode(array("url_unica" => $url_unica));
```

---

Lo que quisiera es mostrar el valor de $url_unica en el SweetAlert, pero esto me imprime "undefined". ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Que alternativas tengo para mostrar los valores de mi ajax.php en el script.js?

El error en consola es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La línea 14 es esta:

```
let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: El problema no es tanto el `undefined`, el mensaje de error es bastante explícito: **estás intentando hacer parse de un json que no es válido**, seguramente porque en `ajax.php` están saliendo más cosas por pantalla. Conviene que pongas todo el código de ese archivo. He comentado esto mil veces ya aquí: cuando esperas un json en el cliente debes controlar todo lo que sale en el servidor, porque si salen cosas de forma indiscriminada tu json se romperá. Para depurar, comenta la línea del parse com `//` y pon un `console.log(response);` así verás lo que te está devolviendo el servidor.

Answer (score 3):

Bien, estas retornado un objeto JSon con la función json_encode que esta correcto.
El problema es como se esta recibiendo en el ajax. No utilices el JSON.parse.
Debes agrega a los parametos del ajax, el tipo de dato que recibes dataType: 'json'.

prueba este codigo:

```
$('#form-firma').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json', //tipo de dato que se recibe
        success: function (response) {
             
            let url_unica = response.url_unica;
                            
            console.log("este es el response: " + response + " fin response");

            //SweetAlert
            Swal.fire({
                html: "<p>Esta es la url_unica: <br> " + url_unica + "</p>",
                icon: 'success',
                toast: false,
                position: 'center',
                showConfirmButton: true
            });
        }
    });
});
```